# Concrete5 Failed opening required

Tags: concrete5

Currently setting up an existing concrete5 website. After running MAMP and running `composer install` I get the following error:

```
Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\MapClassLoader::loadClass(): Failed opening required '/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/packages/components/controller.php' (include_path='/Users/xxx/xxx/xxx/concrete/vendor:.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.19/lib/php')
```

It seems like the folder `components` which it is looking in for the `controller.php` inside `packages` does not exist. How can I fix this?

Comment: How your existing site was installed? Was it a composer based installation?

Comment: @Pimmesz Do you find the `components` package in the composer .json/.lock? If not, the package was added manually. Then the quick fix would be: download the folder from the hosting and set it locally on the required place.

Comment: Yes that seemed to work... Thank you @1stthomas!

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded the folder from the hosting and set it locally on the required place fixed the issue.